# Django UserAdmin customization

Tags: django, model, admin

Within my Users page, I would like to add more column fields to display for each user.

By default, the User page shows username, first name, last name, email, and staff status, but I would also like to add the column "Chosen Groups" to be displayed as well.

Each user can be a part of zero or more groups, so I would like to show a list of all groups (or None) that each user is a part of.

I put something together but I am not sure how to actually get the group data and put it into a "string" form for the "Chosen Groups" column.

Here was my failed attempt...

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined', 'get_groups')

    def get_groups(self, object):
        #code...

#User is registered by default, need to unregister than register to apply custom updates to UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
def get_groups(self, object):
    return u', '.join(g.name for g in object.groups.all()) or 'None'
get_groups.short_description = 'Chosen Groups'
```

To reduce the number of sql queries you can also override the [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.prefetch_related('groups')
```